# Node.js - How to write plugins for application?

Tags: node.js

So I have a node.js application that I want to have plugins that can one or several of the following:

1. Data importer
2. Data outputer
3. Data storage (mongodb)
4. View (express/jade)

So say `plugin A` is a `data storage` and `plugin B` is a `data outputer` and `view` plugin that requires `plugin A`?

Is there any existing framework that can solve this for me?

I think I know how to do it kind of with require and some 'magic', but I have requirements:

- Plugins should `register` with the main application so the application can send events or call methods on the plugin.
- Should be easy to pull in and out plugins
- Should be able to validate that you have the dependency plugins installed for a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to write your plugin as simple Node.js module and, as you already mentioned, `require` it in your main application.

Your plugin has to export an `activate`-function which you call from your main app.

To register functionality (or the plugin itself) in the main application, you could write a node module, that the plugin developer must add to it's developer dependencies. Let's call it plugin-interface-module for now. These module should have a register function which you call inside of your `activate`-function in the plugin.

Your main app also requires these plugin-interface-module and retrieves all registered plugins from it. Required modules are globaly cached, like singletons, so your main app is able to get the list of registered plugins.

Take a look ad VS Vode (https://code.visualstudio.com). It's written in typescript and uses extensions in the same way.